# Can anyone help me with installation of varnish vagent2

Tags: centos, varnish

I want to install this varnish vagent2
https://github.com/varnish/vagent2

I am working around it but it is not installing.. it is giving me following error..

```
root@ns5 [/usr/local/src/vagent2-master]# ./autogen.sh
+ aclocal
configure.ac:65: error: pkg.m4 missing, please install pkg-config
configure.ac:65: the top level
autom4te: /usr/bin/m4 failed with exit status: 1
aclocal: error: echo failed with exit status: 1
```

now i have pkg-config / m4 / latest version of automake / autoconf installed...
yet it is giving this issue. Can anyone guide me as how can i get through the same ?

Comment: What platform are you on

Answer (score 0):

You're missing pkg.m4 it seems?

Check the spec files in the redhat/ directory to determine dependencies. We tested this on centos6 and I believe centos5, but I currently lack easy access to a machine to test from, so before I pursue this further, I suggest you check the spec file.

If that doesn't help, open an issue on github, as we don't generally follow stackoverflow :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to install pkgconfig. On a mac, you may first need to install "mac ports" ... here is an article describing the solution:

http://www.fantageek.com/318/install-pkg-config-for-mac-osx/

Answer (score 0):

Long story short. To get varnish-agent working happily on centos5 you needed to manually update automake and autoconf, which means that aclocal may not look into the right directory for pkg.m4.

Assuming you have installed pkgconfig using yum, line 22 in autogen.sh should look like this below.

`aclocal -I /usr/share/aclocal`

To make this a little easier, I have changed autogen.sh to include the above changes. See commit below, In addition, I have provided a Vagrantfile to illustrate how you can build a happy centos5 vm for varnish-agent. Hope this helps.

https://github.com/varnish/vagent2/commit/3921083f5fef12f06527e3361cc880121aa6b66b